# Unity3D - GameControl always null?

Tags: unity-game-engine, persistence, unityscript, destroy

I don't know what is wrong with my destroy portion of the below code. I'm trying to have only 1 `GameControl` persist throughout the scenes. It seems that every time I switch back to this scene, my `GameControl` is read as null and a new `GameControl` is generated and I end up having more than 1 `GameControl` persisting.

For reference: I tried to port the code from 18:24 to JavaScript from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxziv4ISfys)

Please advise.

```
 #pragma strict

 var control : GameControl;

 function Awake () {
 Debug.Log("GameControl runs");

     if (control == null)
     {
         DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
         control = this;
         Debug.Log(control);
     } else if (control != this)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         Debug.Log("Destroy?");
     }
 }

 function Update ()
 {
 }
```

Comment: @LumbusterTick You're right!! I tried "var static control : GameControl" earlier but that didn't work. Please submit your answer as the answer to this question rather than a comment so I can pick it and give you points!! At least I think that's how it works.. Thank you! :-)

Comment: yeah you need to be carefull with syntax , happens to the best of us , I recommned that you watch a toturial on debugging inside the ediotr you are using , will save you alot of time

Comment: I didn't think about that, good advice! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using a static variable like this:

`static var control : GameControl;`

In simple terms being `static` means this variable will hold the same value across all your scripts thus the check `if(control == null)` will always remain true because your `GameObject` will create a new variable when you load a new scene. This new object is still not static and is therefore completely different. I hope this helps. If you are still confused I'd advise reading some single pattern articles because there are many ways to achieve it other than this.